VBA: Named Range Generator Generating Incorrect Range
Sub SeriesScripts()
Dim lastcol As Long
Dim startrow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master Sheet")
lastcol = ws.Cells(i, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToRight).Column
Set rng = Range(1 & ":" & lastcol)
Debug.Print rng.Address
End Sub


Hi- i am trying to debug this here which returns 1:7620, what I am trying to do is dynamically create series with this across a row- so this realy is intended to say A1:KGB1 > What do I have wrong? it is grabbing 7620 (correct column location) but going down as well> not as KGB1

Your title says "... Named Range Generator...". Are you trying to create a name for each column using the header for the name and the cells below for its range?

.Column returns a number, consider using rng = Range("A1" & ":" & cells(1, lastcol).address)

Where are you setting the value for i?  Your example is not "Complete", which means it is not "Verifiable" — guidance on making a Minimal, Complete, & Verifiable Example can be found at ← that link

If you go right from the last column then you don't move anywhere. You need xlToLeft not xlToRight, and the Range address format you're using is for rows.
Try
Set rng = ws.Cells(i, 1).Resize(1, lastcol)

Not sure I understand exactly what range you want though?  You say 7620 is correct but in that case I'm not sure why you use xlToRight
Using a loop:
Sub SeriesScripts()
    Dim lastcol As Long, i As Long, ws As Worksheet, rng As Range
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master Sheet")
    For i = 1 To 3
        lastcol = ws.Cells(i, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Set rng = ws.Cells(i, 1).Resize(1, lastcol)
        ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="Series_" & i, RefersTo:=rng
    Next i
End Sub


got it- thank you, the end goal though is to have this say
For i = 1 to 24
Range("A"& i).Resize(1, lastcol)
as to iterate dynamic ranges down a worksheet, why does that not work?

In what exact way does it not work?  Can you edit your question to show the code which is using a loop?  What exactly do you need to create using your code?
